# Deshabilitar el check de la cabecera de un datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, checkbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//Deshabilita
$('#tbTodosPDS .dt-checkboxes-select-all').css('pointer-events', 'none');

//Habilita
$('#tbTodosPDS .dt-checkboxes-select-all').css('pointer-events', 'auto');

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta como tal ? Saludos

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto, y más que una pregunta lo que quise es compartir esta solución.

Comment: La forma correcta es escribiendo la pregunta y en el mismo trámite, marcar la opción de responder tu propia pregunta. Agrega información y comentarios que eduquen.

Comment: Gracias @Candid Moe, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Amigos para los que estén buscando que deshabilitar el check principal de su datatables, aquí le dejos una solución muy sencilla de implementar.

Deshabilita
$('#tbTodosPDS .dt-checkboxes-select-all').css('pointer-events', 'none');

Habilita
$('#tbTodosPDS .dt-checkboxes-select-all').css('pointer-events', 'auto');

Saludos.